# ClassificationTree array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, oop, matlab, classification

I am very new to MATLAB.  I was trying to train some ClassificationTree's and the assign them in array with the following snippet

```
for k = 1:rows
   tree=ClassificationTree.fit(data(1:k, 1:cols),labels(1:k));
   ensemble(k)=tree;
end
```

however when I run this I get following error

```
??? Error using ==> DisallowVectorOps>DisallowVectorOps.subsasgn at 28
You cannot assign to an object of class double using () indexing.

Error in ==> dwm02 at 7
ensemble(k)=tree;
```

is there any way of doing this? MATLAB help on object arrays is a bit confusing..

Comment: Is your snippet from a function or from a script? My guess is that the variable ensemble is not empty when you execute your snippet. In this case, try a "clear ensemble" directly before the for loop, or set a debugging breakpoint before the for loop and take a look at the workspace.

Comment: I suspect that this error is telling you that 'ensemble' is an array of doubles and that 'tree', being an object, can't be put into 'ensemble' using () indexing. What if you were to make ensemble a cell array instead? Like ensemble{k}=tree; (with curly braces)

Comment: @kitchenette why not make that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Chris A. Because without reproduction code, I have no way of verifying my response as a true answer vs. speculation. Also, I am anal-retentive. :(

Comment: @kitchenette Thanks, this is the solution, I have found it a long time ago, on Matlab answers, but, for the sake of completeness perhaps you can "asnwer" the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the user kitchenette the answer is using a cell array instead?

```
ensemble{k}=tree;
```